# Is there any way to see deleted questions that have answers?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Is there any way to see deleted questions of other users that have an answer?

Comment: Once you get to 10k, you get to see deleted posts. With a direct URL, you'll be able to see a deleted question.

Comment: [Access to moderator tools](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [access to moderation tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege (which you'll get at 10K reputation on regular sites or 2K on beta sites) will allow you to see deleted questions. Once you have this privilege, you can search for deleted questions with answers by using the search string `deleted:1 answered:1`.

Comment: It should be noted that for regular users the `deleted:1` search parameter will only return that user's own posts. Only moderators can globally search for deleted posts.